# Spark SQL nested JSON error "no viable alternative at input "

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark  SQL nested JSON error :

```
{
  "xxxDetails":{  
      "yyyData":{  
         "0":{  
            "additionalData":{  

            },
            "quantity":80000,
            "www":12.6,
            "ddd":5.0,
            "eee":72000,
            "rrr":false
         },
         "130":{  
            "additionalData":{  
               "quantity":1
            },
            "quantity":0,
            "www":1.0,
            "ddd":0.0,
            "eee":0,
            "rrr":false
         },
         "yyy":{  
            "additionalData":{  
               "quantity":1
            },
            "quantity":0,
            "www":1.0,
            "ddd":0.0,
            "eee":0,
            "rrr":false
         }       
      }
   },
   "mmmDto":{  
      "id":0,
      "name":"",
      "data":null
   }
 }
```

when reading spark.sql("select cast (xxxDetails.yyyData.yyy.additionalData.quantity as Long) as quantity  from table") it will work  but: spark.sql("select cast (xxxDetails.yyyData.130.additionalData.quantity as Long) as quantity  from table") will throw Exception :

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'cast (xxxDetails.yyyData.130.

When I"m usning datafame API for myDF.select("xxxDetails.yyyData.130.additionalData.quantity") its work .
Anyone with decent explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

It's because SQL column names are expected to start with a letter or some other characters like `_`, `@` or `#` but not a digit. Let's consider this simple example:

```
Seq((1, 2)).toDF("x", "666").createOrReplaceTempView("test")
```

Calling `spark.sql("SELECT x FROM test").show()` would output

```
+---+
|  x|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

but calling `spark.sql("SELECT 666 FROM test").show()` instead outputs

```
+---+
|666|
+---+
|666|
+---+
```

because `666` is interpreted as literal, not a column name. To fix this, the column name needs to be quoted using [backticks](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm):

```
spark.sql("SELECT `666` FROM test").show()
```

```
+---+
|666|
+---+
|  2|
+---+
```

Comment: Hi @ollik1 I apologize  I"m updating my example/question with more details, the error still occurs even when I'm using: spark.sql("select cast (xxxDetails.'130'.yyy.quantity as Long) as quantity. again sorry for the first incomplete example.

Comment: This works for me, @ArnonRodman remember it is not single quote but skewed quote, i.e. ```spark.sql("select cast (xxxDetails.yyyData.`130`.additionalData.quantity as Long) as quantity from table")```

Comment: Edited the answer to emphasise using the correct quotation characters

Comment: Thx @ollik1 and Richard Nemeth it worked, where can I find this in the documentation? and why spark.sql API is different from DataFrame.sql API

Comment: Not sure if there is any better documentation than this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3483 which leads to https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2804/files . It does not explain though why backtick was chosen instead of double-quote which would be standard SQL. Dataframe API is different as it is explicit from the method signatures that the passed string refers to a column. SQL string, however, needs to be parsed and analyzed according to certain rules. Note that identifiers starting with a number would also fail in Java, Scala and Python